# jquery .remove() or .hide() only hide uploaded file after click send button it saves the hidden/removed files in database

Tags: asp.net

Hello fellows I have a weird issue:I use file upload to attach files with "X" sign behind when I click the button submit it also sends to the database those which were clicked "X". I can't understand why ? 
I need an advice

Comment: I put on click function and the .hide() or .remove() methods but it only hides the element but sends them to the server :/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the files from the JavaScript object that you are storing the files, according to what element from the html you are removing. That is before sending them to the server.